# Where can i get the source code for VNC in DOtnet c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vnc, vnc-viewer

My requirement is to remove the menu bar of TightVNC Viewer, because i dont want the user to use any of them in menu bar. For which i need the source code of TightVNC, so that i can
remove or disable the menu bar in UI Form. Can i get the source code in c# and i want to
open the project in Visual studio Dot Net and change the form. Or any other ideas for removing the menu bar will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code off the [TightVNC website](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) is C++.

If you're looking specifically for C#, there's an open-source C# VNC client on Sourceforge, [here](http://dnvnccl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

you can download from the .Net based open source project at Sourcefourge. here is the link
http://dotnetvnc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the source code off the [website](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php).

Comment: Anon, i tried that already. Its a c++ version and even in that i am not able to see any form. I dunno c++, thats why i am searching for c# version.

Comment: If the source code isn't in C#, what makes you think there is a C# version available?

Comment: Anon, just tried my luck in the Net for c# version. I also tried with c++ version, but could not find the place of UI !!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but if someone is still searching for a .NET VncViewer, [VnC#](https://cdot.senecacollege.ca/projects/vncsharp/quickstart.html) is a good source code sample.