# what is the best VNC client library for c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vnc

I am researching VNC libraries in C #, for a development in which I work. 
What is in your opinion the best library to write client VNC applications?.
I am currently using 'VNC Sharp' library, but unfortunately it does not work with the latest versions of VNC servers. It only works up to 3.8.

I hope you can help me and provide some other options

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159618/where-can-i-get-the-source-code-for-vnc-in-dotnet-c

Comment: I wrote a C# VNC client/server from scratch once, I recommend it for anyone who hasn't done it before.